# I have been stuck on this homework:

Tags: javascript

Javascript function. Am stuck on this assinment on how to print from 1 to a hundred using nested functions which prints 10 numbers on 1 line and breaks till the 10th line making 100.

Comment: show us what you tried so far

Comment: actually. any short code will do just fine. as long as it prints ten characters on each lines that is 1-10 line one, 11-20 line two till its gets to a hundred. one function can take care of the counting while the other takes car of the breaking

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it - using nested functions:

```
(function(){
  (function(){
    return arguments[1]<11?arguments.callee(
    arguments[0],arguments[1]+1,arguments[2]+' '+
    (arguments[1]+arguments[0]*10)):console.log(arguments[2]);
  }(arguments[0],1,''));
  return arguments[0]<9?arguments.callee(arguments[0]+1):0;
}(0));
```

See [**demo on jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/noxiso/1/edit?js,console).

It will give you extra points for using closures, recursion, immediately invoked function expressions, and not using global variables - thus not polluting the namespace. If you carefully follow the code, fully understand it and be able to explain how it works then you may actually learn much more than doing the homework yourself in the first place.